# Android: Cannot deserialize json into class object with Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, deserialization

Given the next json:

```
{
   "alpha_two_code":"AR",
   "web_pages":[
      "http://www.atlantida.edu.ar/"
   ],
   "name":"Universidad Atlantida Argentina",
   "country":"Argentina",
   "domains":[
      "atlantida.edu.ar"
   ],
   "state-province":null
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into a College object like the next:

```
public class College
{
    @SerializedName(value = "name")
    private String college;
    @SerializedName(value = "country")
    private String country;
    @SerializedName(value = "state-province")
    private String state;
    private Web_Pages web_pages;

    public College()
    {

    }

    public String getCollege()
    {
        return college;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    public String getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public static class Web_Pages
    {
        private String[] url;

        public String[] getUrl()
        {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String[] url)
        {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to deserialize like this:

```
College college = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(json), College.class);
```

But always throwing the next exception:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY in web_pages
```

Any help om how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem myself. Instead of having an inner Web_Pages class, it's enough with a String[] object, so my class definition now looks like this:

```
public class College {
    @SerializedName(value = "name")
    private String college;
    @SerializedName(value = "country")
    private String country;
    @SerializedName(value = "state-province")
    private String state;
    private String[] web_pages;

    public College() {

    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    
    public String[] getWeb_pages(){
        return web_pages;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone else facing the same issue :)